# How to restore .bash_profile on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: shell, path, bash

I've been setting new softwares(mongoDB, maven etc) on my MAC. 
I think I overwrote the original .bash_profile while I worte the new PATH. 
And now most of the basic command in bash shell is not working.

```
-bash: ls: command not found
```

Following is the my .bash_profile opened in text editor.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH

export PATH=/Users/sychung/mongoDB/bin

#maven PATH
export M2_HOME=/Users/sychung/apache-maven-3.1.1
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

And the following is the list of PATH when I typed in "echo $PATH" in the shell.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/sychung/mongoDB/bin:/Users/sychung/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin
```

What should I do to make the bash go back to normal?

Based on other comments, I've typed in the following in the shell and it looked like work again. However, when I restart the terminal, it goes back to "command not found" mode again and again.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH
```

Comment: You only need to export a variable once, not each time you set it.

Comment: You have a bunch of duplicate additions to the `PATH` there too that you can probably clean up. (Also do you need/have both python 2.7 and 3.4?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that `export` will take the current value of `PATH` in your file and append it to the value currently in the environment. However, the `export` command does only one thing: it *marks* the *name* `PATH` with the export attribute. When it comes time to set up the environment for a subprocess, the shell takes the current value of all names with the export attribute and adds them to that environment.

Note that once a process starts, there is no difference between variables with the export attribute set (whether inherited from the parent or set locally) and variables without; they are all simply shell variables.

When you set `PATH` to a single directory, that overwrites the current value of `PATH` and loses all the previous directories you included.

A correct way to add directories to your path is

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH

PATH=$PATH:/new/dircetory
PATH=$PATH:/another/new/one
PATH=/a/very/important/one:$PATH    # you can prepend as well
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the problem is `export PATH=/Users/sychung/mongoDB/bin` which, unlike all the other lines that sets `PATH`, doesn't also include the current `$PATH` value and so removes the default `PATH` entries. Make that line look like the other lines (include `$PATH` somewhere in it) and things should work.